# MS SQL - Grouping Sequential Dates (ignoring weekends and holidays) returning a start date and end date whilst doing a count of hours

Tags: sql-server, date, grouping, datediff

I am hoping someone can help please. I have seen solutions to parts of this issue, but haven't been able to add them all together to pull the data that I need.

I have a table with timesheet entries, each line contains an employee, transaction date, a project code and an amount of hours against it.

Example:

```
Employee, Date, Code, Hours
00001, 2016-08-01, FunProject1, 6.0
00001, 2016-08-01, FunProject2, 2.0
00045, 2016-08-01, FunProject5, 8.0
00086, 2016-08-01, FunProject1, 8.0
```

I also have a table which contains our Standard Holiday/Vacation.

```
HolidayDate, HolidayName
2016-08-30, SomeoneDiedDay
2016-09-01, SomeoneWasBornDay
```

What I would like to do is create a report for the hours which sit against a certain code, and group the dates together creating a start date and an end date for the use of that code and then the total amount of hours against it (assuming 8 hours counts as 1 day).

```
Employee ID, Code, Start Date, End Date, Total Hours, Total Days
00001, FunProject1, 2016-08-01, 2016-08-15, 88, 11
00086, FunProject1, 2016-08-01, 2016-08-01, 8, 1
```

The results should ignore the weekends (starting -365 days prior to current date) and any holidays/vacation from the existing table.

I have sort of got half way there with the below:

```
SELECT Employee, 
       dateadd(d, - row_number() over (partition by Employee order by Date), Date) as StartDate, Date, SUM(Hrs)AS TotalHours
       FROM HrsDetail
WHERE (Code = 'FunProject1' AND DATEPART(YYYY, Date) = '2017' AND (TotalHours != '0.00'))
GROUP BY Employee, Date
```

(This code doesn't include a full year but I wanted to break this down to understand each part of what the query was doing and tackle the grouping first). How do I now go about grouping the dates to exclude the holiday table and weekends?

Any suggestions or pointers welcome!

Comment: Just a quick hint: create and pre-populate helper table `workdays` containing just primary key `ID` and each workday (`date`). Then join with `Employee` by `workdays.workday between Employee.[Start Date] and  Employee.[End Date]`

Comment: If you still have problems I may post a complete SQL - just provide your table names and desired DateStart and DateEnd